# Удалить строки из таблицы по условиям

Tags: python

Есть таблица из которой необходимо удалить строки, если они соответствуют условию, в данном случае, код удаляет строку, если она содержит любое из значений "unknown", "no-redirect", "invalid-callee", "error"

Вот код:

```
import pyexcel as pe
sheet = pe.get_sheet(file_name="report.xlsx")


def filter_row(row_index, row):
    result = [element for element in row if element == "unknown" or element == "no-redirect" or element == "invalid-callee" or element == "error"]
    return len(result)==1

del sheet.row[filter_row]
```

Код работает, но необходимо сделать еще 1 фильтр, чтобы он удалял строку, если она содержит в столбце "call-result" значение "stop-caller" и если в столбце "wait-time" находится значение "0", "1", "2" или "3".

[image: пример таблицы, которую нужно фильтровать]

Comment: не думали переписать в ```if element in ["unknown", "no-redirect", "invalid-callee", "error"]```? и вот это: ```return len(result)==1``` возвращает булевое значение, а вы в ```del sheet.row[filter_row]``` ждете индекс?

Answer (score 0):

Решил таким образом:

```
def filter_0(row_index, row):
    result = [element for element in row if row[4]==0 and element == 'stop-caller']
    return len(result)==1

del sheet.row[filter_0]

def filter_1(row_index, row):
    result = [element for element in row if row[4]==1 and element == 'stop-caller']
    return len(result)==1

del sheet.row[filter_1]

def filter_2(row_index, row):
    result = [element for element in row if row[4]==2 and element == 'stop-caller']
    return len(result)==1

del sheet.row[filter_2]

def filter_3(row_index, row):
    result = [element for element in row if row[4]==3 and element == 'stop-caller']
    return len(result)==1

del sheet.row[filter_3]
```

Comment: и снова: if row[4] in [0, 1, 2, 3] (или range(4)) и все это - одна функция

Comment: я пробовал в одну функцию делать, но почему-то не работало, попробую ваш вариант, он выглядит лучше. я делал так и не работало: result = [element for element in row if row[4]==3 or row[4]==2 or row[4]==1 or row[4]==0 and element == 'stop-caller']